# react: как в функциональном компоненте понять, что было изменено значение атрибута

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, setstate, usestate

есть функциональный компонент React `Header`:

```
const Header = (props) => {
    [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        console.log('создание компонента');
        return props.attr;
    });

    return <div>{value}</div>
```

который вызывается так:

```
<Header attr={attr} />
```

Как я понимаю, в `Header` useState вызовется лишь 1 раз, когда данный компонент будет создан. Если будет меняется значение `attr` повторных вызовов осуществляться не будет (ведь компонент оставался на месте)

Подскажите, а как ВНУТРИ компонента `Header` можно понять, что произошло изменение атрибутов (т.е. новые пропсы отличаются от старых) и сделать какие-то действия, не связанные с отрисовкой (обработать данные и т.п.)?

Т.е. вся логика должна быть только внутри компонента `Header`, снаружи только меняются атрибуты и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно использовать `useEffect` [документация](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#reference)

```html
const Header = (props) => {
    [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        console.log('создание компонента');
        return props.attr;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('new props');
    }, [props.attr]);
    
    return <div>{value}</div>
    }
```

Comment: да, докапался до этого :) хотел к своему вопросу код добавить `useEffect(() => {console.log('DBG', props);}, [props]);`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот эффект будет возникать только когда будет изменяться параметр?

Comment: Да, все правильно. Только нужно помнить, что сравнение предыдущего и текущего значения в массиве происходит по значению. То есть, если это будет объект или массив, то сравнение будет по ссылкам на объекты, а не по их внутренним полям. Поэтому `[props]` следует заменить на `[props.attr]`, где `attr` должен быть строкой или числом.

Comment: А еще нет смысла в передаче функции в `useState` в данном случае.

Comment: А когда есть смысл функцию использовать? В каких ситуациях?